# Laravel update is not updating table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Ok, so my issue is, my ajax call isn't updating correctly. It's the same as many functions as I have, it's just not updating the values. Although, I can run the query on it's own in mysql and it update ok. Function is below:

```
/*
 * "elerts/quicksave" > Update elert from all screen
 */
public function quicksave($id)
{
    $data = (object)Input::get();

    $ev = Events::find($id);
    $ev->limit          = $data->limit;
    $ev->EventEnabled   = $data->EventEnabled;
    $ev->SundayStart    = $data->SundayStart;
    $ev->MondayStart    = $data->MondayStart;
    $ev->TuesdayStart   = $data->TuesdayStart;
    $ev->WednesdayStart = $data->WednesdayStart;
    $ev->ThursdayStart  = $data->ThursdayStart;
    $ev->FridayStart    = $data->FridayStart;
    $ev->SaturdayStart  = $data->SaturdayStart;
    $ev->save();

    $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
    $last_query = end($queries); dd($last_query);

    return "Your eLert has been saved!";
}
```

Below is an example ID getting passed and an example of the $data object that's getting passed.

```
$id = '107';
object(stdClass)#137 (9) { ["limit"]=> string(3) "400" ["EventEnabled"]=> string(1) "1" ["SundayStart"]=> string(1) "0" ["MondayStart"]=> string(1) "0" ["TuesdayStart"]=> string(1) "0" ["WednesdayStart"]=> string(1) "0" ["ThursdayStart"]=> string(1) "1" ["FridayStart"]=> string(1) "1" ["SaturdayStart"]=> string(1) "1"}
```

I'm confused as to why nothing is getting updated. Any help?

EDIT: Below I've included the code for my model so people won't have to question it...

```
<?php
/**
 * @author jmadrigal
 * Date: 7/2/14
 * Time: 10:23 AM
 */
class Events extends Eloquent {

protected $primaryKey = 'eventid';
public $timestamps = false;

protected $fillable = array(
    'eventname', 'eventdescription', 'EventEnabled', 'visitcost',  'groupid', 'flagid', 'SundayStart', 'MondayStart', 'TuesdayStart', 'WednesdayStart', 'ThursdayStart', 'FridayStart',
    'SaturdayStart', 'limit', 'Vtmpl', 'delayV', 'Etmpl', 'delayE', 'Ttmpl', 'delayT', 'Mtemp', 'delayM', 'Login', 'freqv', 'freqt', 'freqe', 'maxe', 'maxt', 'maxv',
    'amtide', 'amtidt', 'amtidv', 'apptinterval'
);

public function aInterval() {
    return $this->hasMany('AppointmentInterval');
}
}
```

Comment: Is your `Events` model a recently added model? Also, if you return `$data` we get `object(stdClass)#137 (9) { ["limit"]=> string(3) "400" ["EventEnabled"]=> string(1) "1" ["SundayStart"]=> string(1) "0" ["MondayStart"]=> string(1) "0" ["TuesdayStart"]=> string(1) "0" ["WednesdayStart"]=> string(1) "0" ["ThursdayStart"]=> string(1) "1" ["FridayStart"]=> string(1) "1" ["SaturdayStart"]=> string(1) "1"}` correct?

Comment: Events model has actually been used for a good minute. It's been there for a couple months. And that's correct. In fact, I'm updating my code to include the model just so people can see where I'm at with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type being sent "string" for any checkbox wasn't going in because the values needed to be an (int) value or a (bool) value of '1' or '0'. That was the issue. Database was set up a year ago by someone else and I didn't catch that until now. It's fixed though.

Comment: I hate when that stuff happens to. Because something so clear can be all kinds of fuzzy when it's not your focus, and the focus is on the code.

Answer (score 5):

More than likely you have not [defined the mass-assignment attributes](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment) your `Events` Model.

So in your `Events` Model try:

```
protected $fillable = array('limit', 'EventEnabled', 'SundayStart', 'MondayStart', 'TuesdayStart', 'WednesdayStart', 'ThursdayStart', 'FridayStart', 'SaturdayStart');
```

This is a security feature of Laravel and helps to prevent against blindly allowing any attributes to be updated.

Comment: I've checked and each variable that's in the object is that's being passed is in the fillable array. But, even so, I'm not mass assigning. I'm assigning every one of them individually so this right here shouldn't even be an issue. If I was dumping the array with ->update($data); I could see why I'd be dealing with this, but this is while I'm assigning them separately.